# MATLAB - Not Enough Input Arguments

Tags: matlab

I am novice in MATLAB. **My code written is really basic**. I am earning it to implement Numerical Methods for CFD. 
I was trying to find f where f is as shown in image below - f is on right

[image: f]

I have written a code in Editor to calculate f for given value of x and given degree n.

```
function result = myFunc(n,x)
    % C = [1, 1./[1:n]];
    % above expression means the following:
    C = [1];
    vec = [1:n];
    C = [C, 1./vec];
    a = [1, x.^vec];
    result = C.*a;
end
```

I am getting an error (as shown above) when I call `myFunc` from the Command Window (also shown above). I have seen some posts here that say to click on the green run button. I can do that but I also want to do it using the Command Window.

Comment: I tried following in command Prompt x=5; n=5; myFunc. Still I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to understand how MATLAB handles function calls. MATLAB uses filenames when using the command prompt.
By calling "myFunc" in the command prompt, MATLAB searches for a file named myFunc.m on the MATLAB path and runs the first function in that file (if there is a function defined in the file). The arguments passed to myFunc() will be directly fed to the function. To clearify:

Imagine a file foo.m with the content

```
function bar(input)
    print input
end
```

When writing

```
foo("Hello World");
```

MATLAB searches for the file foo.m, finds the function bar(input) and calls the function with the given argument "Hello World". "Hello World" appears in the command prompt. However, calling

```
bar("Hello World")
```

will result in an error, as there is no file bar.m on the path.

It is strongly recommended to name the first function in a file identical to the filename itself. But it is not required.

Hope that helps a bit

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the input arguments when running myFunc.

You stated in your function

```
 results = myFunc(n,x)
```

This means that whenever you call myFunc; it has to have those variables present.

next time type in

```
 results = myFunc(10,2)
```

or any other numbers and it should work

Comment: ok. Suppose my command prompt is new and now i need to call this function myFunc(n,x). So, to do that, I need to call the file containing this function. Because I know that this error will come, I predefined x=5, n=5 in command prompt and then tried to call file myFunc. but got same error. So, Basically, I am asking is how to call this function in a totally blank command prompt ?

Comment: you still have to feed the arguments into your function. if you don't want to feed in variables then you have to remove them from the function. But doing this can cause problems with programming as some functions will not look at the environment to grab these variables.

pretty much, if you want to feed in variables, you have to always define them

Comment: Ahan. Got your point. But what about calling myFunc in totally blank Command Prompt. I tried following code. n=5; x=5; myFunc and still got that error

Comment: Just to make sure of my concepts. My file name and function name is same. So, when I write myFunc in a blank command prompt, Exactly what  is being called, the file myFunc.m or the function myFunc ?

Comment: I tried writing result = myFunc(6,1.15) and got the answer. But, how does the command prompt knows (totallt empty earlier) where and which function is this ? Does it searches whole of Current Folder menu on left ??

Comment: The m file is being called which will then run the function that is within it. This is partly why you can't pre-define the variables and then run the function. just type myFunc(5,5) and your code should work.

Comment: Yep. It worked but since the command prompt was clear, how does solver knows where to get this function or which m file it has to choose ?

Comment: every function will have its own unique name. So myFunc should theoretically be the only one. If there are multiples then it will run the first one it finds. As for where the function is located; matlab has a directory of where functions are located. If your function is not in the path then it will not know or run it. You will have to add the path in matlab every time load up matlab.

Comment: As an example, exit out of matlab and open it. Try running your function by typing in myFunc and it should give you an error. This is because the function directory was not identified in matlab. One way to add it is to perform the **addpath** function. If your lazy, go into your code, click the run button. matlab should complain saying that the function is in a different directory and would like to add it. Just hit yes and it will perform the **addpath** function for you.

Comment: Yep. Did that and got the error of path. Did as you told and matlab added the file path  itself. Since saying thanks is banished here, so thought to do this. function LearntSuccessfully =  MATLAB (Hojo)